# Optional to Required relationship

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following model

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Child LastChild { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Child> Children { get; set; } 
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is to make two relationships:

- ONE parent with MANY children
- ONE parent with OPTIONAL ONE child.

Now I have the following code for the model builder:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
            .HasKey(child => child.Id);

modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
            .HasKey(parent => parent.Id)
            .HasMany(parent => parent.Children)
            .WithRequired(child => child.Parent)
            .HasForeignKey(child => child.ParentId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
            .HasOptional(parent => parent.LastChild)
            .WithRequired(children => children.Parent);
```

The One to Many relationship causing no problem, but the Zero or One to One is causing the following exception:

> Parent_LastChild_Target: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Parent_LastChild_Target' in relationship 'Parent_LastChild'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

Is this kind of relationship possible under entity-framework? And if it does how can I achieve the desired relationship?

Comment: I don't know enough of EF to know if it supports that but I was wondering why you didn't make your property LastChild like the following: `public Child LastChild { get { return Children.LastOrDefault(); } }`

Comment: Navigation properties in EF can be either `Optional (ie 0..1 to x), Required (ie 1 to x) or Many (ie * to x)`

Comment: @MarcelGosselin I did so for better performance mostly, the model in the question is just an example. In the real model each parent is going to have thousands of children. One of the details pages is design to show latest activities and it would be a waste to enumerate through the entire 'Children' table to find to first one related to the parent.

Comment: @Avijit Does `x` stands for either `Optional, Required and Many`?

Comment: `x` stands for `many`

Comment: You should probably add a `LastChildId` to your `Parent` class and add the appropriate `HasKey` mapping. Otherwise, how does the EF know which child is the latest?

Comment: This is **An XY Problem**: Stop trying to address performance directly in your model (ie Logical/Conceptual Design), and simply create the appropriate index in your Physical Design. (Link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)